# Calling a stored procedure within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, export-to-csv, nested-function

I am trying to call a function within a function using sql on postgres 9.3.

This question is related to [another post by me](http://bit.ly/1hB2Hn3).

I have written the below function. So far I have failed to incorporate any kind of save-output (COPY) statement, so I am trying to work around this by creating a nested function print-out function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION retrieve_info(TEXT, TEXT) RETURNS SETOF   
retrieve_info_tbl AS $$
 SELECT tblA.id, tblA.method, tblA.species, tblA.location
 FROM tblA
 WHERE method=$1 AND species=$2
 GROUP BY id, method, species
 ORDER BY location
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

The above function works.

An attempt to create a nested function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION print_out(TEXT, TEXT) RETURNS void AS $$
 COPY (SELECT * FROM retrieve_info($1, $2)) TO 'myfilepath/test.csv'    
 WITH CSV HEADER;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

Calling nested function.

```
SELECT * FROM print_out('mtd1','sp1');
```

**OUTPUT**

The above gives this `ERROR: column "$1" does not exist SQL state: 42P02 Context: SQL function "print_out" statement 1`. However, when substituting the arg1, arg2 in print_out() with 'mtd1','sp1' the correct output is printed to test.csv (as seen below)

```
id | method | ind | location
----------------------------
1a | mtd1   | sp3 | locA
1d | mtd1   | sp3 | locB
```

How would I get the arg1, arg2 of retrieve_info() to call arg1, arg2 properly within print_out()?

I am completely stuck. Would appreciate any pointers, thanks

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019508/copy-with-dynamic-file-name/16021835#16021835 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991383/postgres-copy-from-variable-with-csv-data/16991854#16991854

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) is a bit odd as it sort of treats its `query` argument as a string even though it isn't written as a string. The result is that the `query`:

```
SELECT * FROM retrieve_info($1, $2)
```

isn't executed in the context of the function, it is executed in the context of COPY itself. Even though you say:

```
copy (select * from t) ...
```

it is treated more as though you wrote:

```
copy 'select * from t' ...
```

so by the time the query is executed, the function parameters no longer have any meaning, the `query` argument to COPY may look like it would behave like a closure in other languages but it doesn't, it acts more like a string that gets passed to `eval`.

You can get around this strangeness by using the usual Kludge of Last Resort: [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). You should get better results if you write your function to use string wrangling and EXECUTE:

```
create or replace function print_out(text, text) returns void as $$
begin
    execute 'copy ('
         || 'select * from retrieve_info'
         ||     '(' || quote_literal($1) || ',' || quote_literal($2) || ')'
         || ') to ''myfilepath/test.csv'' with csv header;';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. The above above code fails at `with` csv. Changing it to just ...`.csv'''';` (think I've seen that somewhere) seems to work, but calling it I get the message `ERROR: function print_test(unknown, unknown) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 15`

Comment: I don't see any `print_test` anywhere. It worked for me as in my answer, did you mess up the nested quotes somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. They are called slightly different in the real code. I think it looks correct(?), please have a look at this [print screen](http://i1326.photobucket.com/albums/u642/Awful-Dodger/ScreenShot2013-11-14at75409PM_zps5a693e66.png)

Comment: You're missing a doubled single quote after "to": `') to '/Users` should be `') to ''/Users`.

Comment: Ah, thanks and thanks for baring with me. However, the nested function doesn't seem to be recognized [print screen](http://i1326.photobucket.com/albums/u642/Awful-Dodger/ScreenShot2013-11-14at82456PM_zpsc13e4a41.png)

Comment: You're still using this mystery `print_test` function and I have no way of know what that is or how it is defined. You're defining a `print_out` function but calling `print_test` and wondering why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, yeah. Sorry! Too tired to keep track of the function names yesterday! You're completely right, now it works! Many thanks!!

Comment: @jO. You may be interested in `format()` to simplify string concatenation while automatically quoting values and identifiers. I posted several related answers with more details. [Like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019508/copy-with-dynamic-file-name/16021835#16021835)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Thanks for the quote fix; I think that might be the first time I've quoted the language and of course you'd spot it.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: You can run, but you cannot hide! ;) Honestly, I was surprised, coming from you ... But then again, if it's any consolation, I [caught myself in the act, too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361660/how-to-convert-this-t-sql-code-to-postgresql-plpgsql/7856148#7856148) [Twice!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507184/postgresql-stored-procedure-using-ibatis/7947599#7947599) Copy/paste is a bitch. Anyway, good answer, shenanigans aside.

Answer (score 0):

Are `x` and `y` quoted intentionally?

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM retrieve_info('x','y')) TO 'myfilepath/test.csv'
```

You are not sending the `x` and `y` arguments of `print_out` to `retrieve_info` - rather, you are sending the strings `'x'` and `'y'`. Assuming you don't have records with `method='x' AND species='y'`, it's of little wonder you get no results.

Try this instead:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM retrieve_info(x,y)) TO 'myfilepath/test.csv'
```

Comment: Thanks your comment. Yes, your right. Stupid of me to leave the quotes (now removed). I've already tested without, but get the this error message after calling the function 

`ERROR: column "x" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Context: SQL function "print_out" statement 1`

Comment: shouldn't it be @x and @y since they are passed in variables?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: Since you have been able to help me before, maybe you can give this a shot as well? Do you have any idea how to e.g. add a COPY statement within a function and/or calling a function within a function? Would appreciate any help on this, thanks

Comment: @Matt: Thanks for your comment. Tried @x,@y, $x,$y and $1, $2 to reference x, y in retrieve_info() but without success...

Comment: I have 'undefined' the arguments x, y in trying to make it possible using reference $1, $2