# Postgres Anonymous Code Block Syntax Error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm having a hard time here with pl-pgsql syntax.

here's the code:

```
DO $$
DECLARE 
dia_semana INT := CAST(EXTRACT(DOW FROM CURRENT_DATE)as INT);
dia INT :=  CASE WHEN dia_semana = 0 THEN dia := 7;
         WHEN dia_semana = 1 THEN dia := 6;
         WHEN dia_semana = 2 THEN dia := 5;
         WHEN dia_semana = 3 THEN dia := 4;
         WHEN dia_semana = 4 THEN dia := 3;
         WHEN dia_semana = 5 THEN dia := 2;
         WHEN dia_semana = 6 THEN dia := 1;
BEGIN   
COPY(SELECT CURRENT_DATE + dia)
TO '/tmp/dump.sql';
END $$;
```

raises the error:

**'LINE 4:  dia INT := CASE WHEN dia_semana = 0 THEN dia := 7;'**

with cursor on ":" "dia:= 7".
Already tried a normal assignment "dia = 7" without success. Can someone please lend me a hand here?

tnx.

Answer (score 2):

There is no semicolon `;` between the cases neither the assignment inside each case. This `case` syntax is better here

```
dia int := case dia_semana

    when 0 then 7
    when 1 then 6
    when 2 then 5
    when 3 then 4
    when 4 then 3
    when 5 then 2
    when 6 then 1
    end;
```

But you can simple do

```
dia int := 7 - dia_semana;
```

Comment: Hi Clodoaldo, tnx for the help got that "case" issue handled now. But the code still doesn't work. PGSQL is treating my variable as a column... heres the message: "ERROR:  column "dia" don't exist
LINE 1: COPY(SELECT CURRENT_DATE + dia)"

Comment: @XVirtusX: I think you'll need to build your COPY as a string and EXECUTE it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19970705/479863

Comment: @XVirtusX I can't reproduce the error. Show the modified code

Comment: @muistooshort How should I concatenate the variable with the string? I tried the following... didnt work out:                     "execute 'COPY(SELECT CURRENT_DATE + ' || dia ||')' ||
  'TO /home/tmp/dump.sql';

Comment: @XVirtusX That error does not happen to me in 9.3. What is your version?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto 9.1. It's really an odd error. If I substitute my var for an integer COPY(SELECT CURRENT_DATE + 1) it works fine.

Comment: @XVirtusX: This should be easy to solve. Post a new question with complete information (verbatim code and error message).